# Gunicorn loggin with django outputs "[DEBUG] 2 workers" every second

Tags: debugging, logging, gunicorn

Got an interesting problem I can't seem to solve or find any answers to..

Gunicorn process is started by supervisor with:

```
gunicorn django_app:application --name django --workers 2 --log-level=debug --bind=127.0.0.1:8003
```

Application runs fine and the logfile logs as it should.. but also gets a log every seconds stating the number of workers running:

```
[2015-12-04 07:28:38 +0000] [5168] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-12-04 07:28:39 +0000] [5168] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-12-04 07:28:40 +0000] [5168] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-12-04 07:28:41 +0000] [5168] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-12-04 07:28:42 +0000] [5168] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-12-04 07:28:43 +0000] [5168] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-12-04 07:28:44 +0000] [5168] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-12-04 07:28:45 +0000] [5168] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-12-04 07:28:46 +0000] [5168] [DEBUG] 2 workers
[2015-12-04 07:28:47 +0000] [5168] [DEBUG] 2 workers
```

This makes debugging a royal pain and I'd like to get the logger to stop logging those messages.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Make Your own `Logger` class which inherit from `gunicorn.glogging.Logger`. Overwrite `debug` function. In this function reject this kind of message.

And finally run `gunicorn --logger-class MyLoggerClass .....`